# Select the difference of two consecutive columns

Tags: sql, select

I have a table car that looks like this:

```
| mileage | carid |
------------------
|   30    |   1   |
|   50    |   1   |
|   100   |   1   |
|   0     |   2   |
|   70    |   2   |
```

I would like to get the average difference for each car. So for example for car 1 I would like to get ((50-30)+(100-50))/2 = 35. So I created the following query

```
SELECT AVG(diff),carid FROM (
  SELECT (mileage-
    (SELECT Max(mileage) FROM car Where mileage<mileage AND carid=carid GROUP BY carid)) 
    AS diff,carid 
  FROM car GROUP BY carid)
```

But this doesn't work as I'm not able to use current row for the other column. And I'm quite clueless on how to actually solve this in a different way.
So how would I be able to obtain the value of the next row somehow?

Comment: if your RDBMS is SQL Server, research the Lead() and Lag() funcitons

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: That's not specific to SQL Server. It's (ANSI) standard SQL and also supported by Postgres, Oracle, DB2, SAP HANA, Ingres, Teradata, Vertica and several others.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Good to know; thank you. I have only really worked with SQL Server for about 10 years now.

Answer (score 2):

The average difference is the maximum minus he minimum divided by one less than the count (you can do the arithmetic to convince yourself this is true).

Hence:

```
select carid,
       ( (max(mileage) - min(mileage)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)) as avg_diff
from cars
group by carid;
```

Comment: Gordon, out of pure curiosity, could you provide some reference for this "math operation"?

Comment: @ConsiderMe . . . Look at your formula.  The intermediate value of 50 drops out of the formula.  This is true of all intermediate values.

Comment: By "my formula" I'm guessing you mean the OP sample data. I don't disagree with the point. I'm simply interested in some reference for this phenomenon :)